# pyTesseract recognize a pattern of text

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to do a simple license plate recognizer. Currently my problem comes from Tesseract messing some readings (for example 5 as S). I know the images are always going to be three uppercase characters, followed by three digits, in the form AAA 999 or so. Is there any way I can give this info to the OCR?

Comment: If you have not done so already, I suggest that you check out the pyimagesearch ANPR tutorial: https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/09/21/opencv-automatic-license-number-plate-recognition-anpr-with-python/

Comment: @Sheldon Many Thanks! I hadn't stumbled upon it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tesseract allows to whitelist specific characters using the `tessedit_char_whitelist` parameter.

A way to address your license plate identification problem would be to split your detection window in two "subwindows", and:

- whitelist letters for the first subwindow (`tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`)
- whitelist numbers for the second subwindow (`tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789`)

Comment: Thanks! Any hint on how could I do these "subwindows"?

Comment: How are you detecting the plate's contour in your current implementation?

Comment: Just a box, labeled them and trying to train YOLO to detect them

Comment: OK, then you may use the width of this box to create your "subwindows": the first ranging from 0 to width/2, the second from width/2 to width.